# getImageData cross-origin error

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, cors

Precursor: I know there have been a few questions already asked about this topic, but none of them seem to offer a straight JavaScript only solution.

So I ran into this error where I am trying to get the pixel data from a canvas using something like `context.getImageData()`, my exact code can been seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/YBt9k/3/)** or below:

```html
<canvas id="imageCanvas" width="600" height="800"></canvas>
```

```js
// Load Image
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');

var image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://emoticons.pw/emoticons/emoticon-faces-002-medium.png';
image.onload = function() {

    width=image.width;
    height=image.height;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle="#024359"; // canvas background color
    context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    context.drawImage(this,0,0);

    imageData = context.getImageData(0,0,width, height); // PROBLEM HERE

    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

I get the following errors in Chrome:

> Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been
>   tainted by cross-origin data.

and then a security error as well. I don't want to make server changes or start chrome with a weird instruction thing. I feel like there has to be something I can do in JavaScript.

Using local images only is not a problem, but when trying that, I got the same error!

I am trying to do this without a server, if I put this on my "default" godaddy web server, are all my problems solved? I heard rumors dropbox could also simulate a server close enough?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use `file://` if you're using that (Chrome allow you to override this but I won't recommend it).

For local testing use a light-weight server such as [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/downloads/) which allow you use `http://localhost` as a domain to test your local pages. This way you avoid problems with CORS.

If you need to host images on a different domain you need to make sure they support cross-origin usage.

DropBox and ImgUrl (I recommend the latter for just images) both support CORS usage, but you need to request such usage by adding the `crossOrigin` property to your image before setting the source (or include it in the HTML tag if you're using that):

```
var img = new Image;

img.onload = myLoader;
img.crossOrigin = '';              ///=anonymous
img.src = 'http://imgur.com/....';
```

or in HTML:

```
<img src="..." alt="" crossOrigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: +1 ... what Ken said, and also put image.onload before image.src

Comment: I always put onload before src just in case .src wins the race.  Brings up a question...will onload fire if src does win the race?

Comment: @markE yes, this is the way I do it too. If I haven't turned blind I believe I also do this here? :) The chance is minimal but theoretical possible so to be more safe than sorry I also put onload before src.

Comment: All good :)  Just wondering if there's any edge case where src before onload causes problems.  I suspect no problems will ever occur because js will attach onload to the image object during js's pre-flight.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put the `img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');` before you set the source of your image object. just like this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
//fix crossorigin here...
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
//after that put your source
img.src = imageSrcURL;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```