# Can't use remote images with jquery.facedetection

Tags: javascript, jquery, face-detection

I'm trying to use this handy jquery wrapper for JS face detection.

https://github.com/jaysalvat/jquery.facedetection

It works fine for local images but not for remote images?!?

The error returned is "The image is not valid".

Any thoughts on why this might be (security? caching?)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK,

So it seems that the script cannot get the (remote) image data due to a cross domain issue.
(as discussed here: [getImageData cross-origin error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869150/html5-canvas-element-getimagedata-cross-origin-error)).

Now when loading the remote image, I add crossOrigin="anonymous" to the img tag.

This seems to have resolved it...

Comment: on loading the image I added the crossorigin attribute and then applied facedetection and this returned: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`