# alternatives for canvas.toDataURL() SecurityError

Tags: javascript, security, html2canvas

What kinds of alternative mechanisms can be used to pass image data, as this is throwing a security issue due to CORS.

Comment: Could you explain with code or is it like this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869150/getimagedata-cross-origin-error ?

Comment: its showing this, as its due to cross origin : SecurityError: The operation is insecure